# Delete row beneath specific value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This question is similar to attached except I don't have any `np.nan` values. [How to delete row based on row above? Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290070/how-to-delete-row-based-on-row-above-python-pandas)

Essentially I'm just trying to `delete` the `row` after a specific value. For the `df` below I want to delete the `row` after `'Foo'`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'A' : ['X','Y','','X','Y'],           
    'B' : ['Foo',np.nan,'','Foo',np.nan],
    'C' : ['X','Y','','X','Y'],
    })
```

Can you just shift the following +1?

```
dl = df.loc[df['B'] != 'Foo']
```

My intended output is:

```
   A    B  C
0  X  Foo  X
1           
2  X  Foo  X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change condition for equal, `shift` and filter by inverted boolean mask:

```
dl = df[~(df['B'] == 'Foo').shift().fillna(False)]
print (dl)
   A    B  C
0  X  Foo  X
2           
3  X  Foo  X
```